# Ionic execute a method after list is loaded

Tags: list, ionic-framework

is it possible to execute a  function after
a Ionic list has iterated through all its elements?

```
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item collection-repeat="event in events">
     {{  event.title }}

    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

So when all elements are loaded on the list I would like to execute a method.

I see I can use $timeout but maybe there is a better way.